# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when using react-router-dom in index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement BroserRouter in index.js file. But I get the error.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const app = (<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render( app, document.getElementById( 'root' ));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `<App />` inside a `<Switch></Switch>` and as an attribute of `<Route>`.

Do not forget to use `exact` attribute for just one of the routes. (Just for your main page like Index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const app = (<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <App />} />
    {/*  Other routs:  */}
    <Route path="/Component2" render={() => <Component2 />} />
    <Route path="/Component3" render={() => <Component3 />} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```